# Spring Cloud Data Flow on Amazon ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, spring-cloud-dataflow

Are there any implementations of the Spring Cloud Data Flow Service Provider Interface for Amazon EC2 Container Service as a runtime platform?

Does it make sense to consider using ECS as a runtime platform for Spring Cloud Data Flow?

If there are no current implementations does anyone know of any plans to implement one? This would seem to fit in the existing 'Spring Cloud for Amazon Web Services' project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't any plans for [Spring Cloud Deployer](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer) SPI implementation for ECS. Likewise, there aren't anything officially scheduled for SCDF implementation either.

The SPI abstraction is setup for easier extension and we encourage users to implement for different runtime platforms where they see fit. For example, please check out the community implementations of SCDF for [Nomad](https://github.com/donovanmuller/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-nomad) and [Openshift](https://github.com/donovanmuller/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-openshift) platforms.

> Does it make sense to consider using ECS as a runtime platform for Spring Cloud Data Flow?

From the surface, it looks like the primitives to orchestrate Docker containers is in ECS. We distribute Docker variant of [stream](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/#stream-app-starters-and-spring-cloud-data-flow-) and [task](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-task-app-starters/#task-app-starters-and-spring-cloud-data-flow-) app-starters, too. Apart from this, routing, LB, logging, security, HA, and resilient orchestration of apps (*embedded in SCDF streams/tasks*) matter for production deployments. You may have to dig into these specifics for decision.

Comment: Are you able to figure out the AWS implementation of SCDF? - @david-geary

Comment: Is it a good option to Configure Kubernetes on AWS and use , SCDF Spring Cloud Data Flow with Kubernetes on AWS.

Comment: Sure thing! It'd be equally a good option to provision any supported platforms (cf, k8s, yarn, mesos) for SCDF for that matter. You'd use the core AWS IaaS infrastructure (VMs) and provision the platform of your choice and [SCDF](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/#spring-cloud-data-flow-implementations). The provisioning aspect could be automated via scripting tools such as CloudFormation, Chef, or Puppet, etc.

Comment: For those like myself that don't want to have to setup and manage a container infrastructure for a few SCDF applications - there may be hope in the form of AWS "managed" Kubernetes service - https://aws.amazon.com/eks/.